# Noob with a logic issue. Using IF, AND...maybe OR? I don't know

Tags: microsoft-excel

A noob user going in circles with my logic. It is for stock options trading where I want to know 3 things. 1) If trade is either open or closed, 2) If DTE (Days till expiration) is above/below certain number (15 days), and 3) how close is stock price to my strike price in percent. (ex. current stock price is 100 my strike price is 91 = 9.89% "below" current price). I have tested all variations of conditions and it **almost** works. Here is current formula =if(AND(H25>=15, K25>=0.1),"DTE and % are good", IF(P25="Open","DTE or % is bad", "Closed so doesn't matter")).

What I want:
If position is "closed" then I don't care what other conditions are either above/below criteria as this is the dominating factor. If position is "Open" then it matters if either 1 or both are true (either DTE is less than equal to 15 or percent is less than equal to 10%) then I want to know.

What works:
If I play with numbers of DTE or % it appears to work just fine as I get "DTE or % is bad" while status = "Open". When I change either DTE or % to trigger a fail and then switch from "Open" to "Closed" I get correct response of "Closed so it doesn't' matter". The problem is when DTE AND % are **ABOVE** the criteria (meaning they don't trigger a fail) and Status is "Closed" I get "DTE and % are good". I would want it to also say "closed so it doesn't matter".

I am sure I am confusing IF, AND, OR usage. I appreciate the help.

My 3 columns are:

**Status(Column P)** - I manually type in  either "Open" or "Closed" in text form.

**% from current price() Column K** - formatted as a percent and calculating ((current price - strike price)/ strike price)).

**DTE (Days to expiration) Column H** - calculates difference in 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just "go the other way" with your logic so that it matches the "word problem" language.

Test for the item being Closed FIRST. Then check for both of the other two conditions being good. And the dumping ground for all remaining would be at least one is bad.

So:

```
=IF(P25="Closed","Closed so doesn't matter",  IF(AND(H25>=15, K25>=0.1),"DTE and % are good",  "DTE or % is bad"))
```

First all Closed items are "removed" (formula stops and tells you it is closed). The only items not passing that test are Open items. Next these are tested for BOTH conditions being TRUE and if so, it is reported so and those items are "removed" (formula stops and tells you both are good). All that remains are items which are Closed, but one or both of the two other conditions is unacceptable. At this point the formula stops as you don't need more detail.

A nested `IF()` like this is basically removing items from the testing and moving deeper into the tests. So it almost always works best (simplest, least further nesting) by removing the most starkly clear cases first as those are the easiest to characterize and when you get to the furthest set (those with the most complicated sets of conditions), you often can, as here, just dump them all together into a "who cares?" bucket.

Not always, of course, but usually. Definitely in this case.

Side note:  there is a function called `IFS()` that is a natural for this kind of thing. With one that has just one, two, maybe three conditions, a short nested `IF()` is pretty clear and easy to maintain. But more conditions start to get very "dense" looking and are hard to understand, and so to maintain, or to explain to a boss who wants to be sure your work is valid.

Doing it using `Alt-Enter` in the formula so there are multiple lines in it, one can put each condition and result on its own line. 15 conditions? 15 lines for them, one each. Easy to read and understand each one, easy to update, remove, or add conditions. Easy for a boss to understand your work and approve it.

Comment: I knew it was simple enough I was just probably staring at it too long and needed a sanity check. In my head it made sense but I am not a expert at formulas. Thank you very much it works flawlessly!